# Refresh page to see content

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've created a Rails app using Backbone, but I've run into a small but annoying problem. When a user goes to his profile and then back to the frontpage the frontpage is empty and I have to refresh it in order to show the content of the backbone view.

In my `Movieseat.Routers.Movieseats` I have:

```
routes:
  '': 'index'

initialize: ->
  @movieSeats = new Movieseat.Collections.Movieseats()
  @movieSeats.fetch()

  @searchResults = new Movieseat.Collections.Moviesearch()

index: ->
  view = new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex(collection: @movieSeats)
  $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

Any idea on why users have to refresh to see the frontpage?

Comment: Is your `index` router getting called? Is the profile page handled through Backbone?

Comment: No the profile page is just a Rails page. Doesn't `view = new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex(collection: @movieSeats)
  $('#container').html(view.render().el)` this create a new view instance and render it to container when the index page is loaded?

Comment: Is your `index` being called? Is everything properly set up when it is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know CoffeeScript but the `fetch()` method takes a success callback where you can ensure the collection has loaded. In your **index** you're creating a new view passing the `@movieSeats` collection but the collection may have **not** been loaded by that time. Try the following:

```
{
  routes: {
    '': 'index'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.movieSeats = new Movieseat.Collections.Movieseats();
  },

  index: function() {
    var self = this, view;

    this.movieSeats.fetch({
      success: function(collection) {
        view = new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex({ collection: collection })
        $('#container').html(view.render().el)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However, you might want to "bootstrap" your collection like is shown on the Backbone docs: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap

Comment: I've tried your methode but it still doesn't show the view when I revisit the homepage. I'm going to try if I can use the `bootstrap` methode.